# Calling to JSON file in ASP.NET MVC 4

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, json

I started to learn `ASP.NET MVC 4`, did some small stuff...

In my index page I want to get `JSON` file with some data and display it on the main page.

In simple `HTML,JavaScript` I using ajax to `GET/POST` `JSON` data

```
<script>
$.ajax({
     type : "GET",
     dataType : "json",
     url : "www.site.com",
     success: function(data){
           alert(data);
     }
});
</script>
```

I created `MVC 4` project, where should I call the jQuery `$.ajax` command to get data and display it ?

Do I have to call it in the View? and with the jQuery syntax?

I'll be happy to see any example

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could put this in a separate javascript file that could be referenced from your view. For example:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/scripts/myscript.js"></script>
```

and inside the script make the AJAX call:

```
$.ajax({
    type : "GET",
    dataType : "json",
    url : "/SomeController/SomeAction",
    success: function(data) {
        alert(data);
    }
});
```

The controller action you are invoking should obviously return a JsonResult:

```
public ActionResult SomeAction()
{
    var model = new
    {
        Foo = "Bar",
    }
    return Json(model, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

There's a further improvement to be made to this javascript. You may notice the hardcoded url to the controller action:

```
url : "/SomeController/SomeAction",
```

This is not good because the pattern of your urls is governed by routes and if those routes change you will also have to modify your javascript. Also if you deploy your application inside a virtual directory in IIS, this path no longer will take into account the virtual directory name.

For this reason it is always recommended to use url helpers to generate the url to a controller action. For example you could store this into a global javascript variable in the view:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var myActionUrl = '@Url.Action("SomeAction", "SomeController")';
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/scripts/myscript.js"></script>
```

and then in your javascript file use this variable:

```
$.ajax({
    type : "GET",
    dataType : "json",
    url : myActionUrl,
    success: function(data) {
        alert(data);
    }
});
```

Comment: Or one question is `var model = new {}` what is meaning of this because I am newbie ...please tell me @Darin Dimitrov

Answer (score 2):

Try the following

Controller

```
public class JsonController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Simple()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public JsonResult SimpleJson()
    {
        var persons = new List<Person>
        {
            new Person{Id=1, FirstName="Harry", LastName="Potter"},
            new Person{Id=1, FirstName="James", LastName="Potter"}
        };

        return Json(persons, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}

public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

In simple.aspx view

```
<head runat="server">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Simple</title>
    <script src="../../Scripts/jquery-2.0.3.intellisense.js"></script>
    <script src="../../Scripts/jquery-2.0.3.js"></script>
    <script src="../../Scripts/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#FillButton').click(function () {
                $.getJSON("/Json/SimpleJson", null, function (data) {
                    var div = $('#ajaxDiv');
                    $.each(data, function (i, item) {
                        div.append("<br /><br />First Name: " + item.FirstName);
                        div.append("<br />Last Name: " + item.LastName);
                    });
                });
            });
        });
    </script>


    <div>
          <div id="ajaxDiv">
        </div>
       <input id="FillButton" type="button" value="Get Persons" />        
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to make ajax call in view, just call MVC url which return json data and operate on that data.

```
<script>
$.ajax({
 type : "GET",
 dataType : "json",
 url : "www.site.com/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
 success: function(data){
       alert(data);
 }
});
</script>
```

pass the Controller, Action and Id part whichever is applicable in the ajax call.
Hope this will help you

Answer (score 1):

You can call ajax function from your view, like below.

```
    var oModel = {};
    oModel.Id = $('#hiddenid').val();
    oModel.Name = $('#hiddenName').val();;  

      $.ajax({
            url: "/SomeController/SomeActionMethod",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: JSON.stringify(oModel),
        }).done(function (data) {
            alert(JSON.stringify(data));
        });
```

and have method named "SomeActionMethod" in your controller like below,

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult SomeActionMethod(oModel oVarModel)
    {
         //Do some stuff

        return someReturn;
    }
```

Hope this helps.