# Why doesn't my data get displayed in a textbox?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using a jQuery function to get data from the database when I press f12 in my response body I can see the data but its not placing anything in. this is how my function looks like:

```
function MethodName() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "@Url.Action("MethodName", "ControllerName")",
        data: JSON.stringify(),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",

        success: function (msg) {
            $('.someText').val(msg);
        }
    });
}
```

This is my empty div and in here I would like to place my text:

```
<div class="someText"></div>
```

Why doesn't it work? I try removing `dataType: "json",` but nothing appears in my div

Comment: You're looking for `$('.someText').html(msg);` or `$('.someText').text(msg);`

Comment: `val()` is used to set a `value` of an element, `div` has not the said property.

Comment: @GôTô I used your suggestion `$('.someText').text(msg)` I get [object Object] on my screen

Comment: are you sure you want a post request? not a get request?

Comment: @User911 What are you hoping to display? If the response is JSON and is likely defining an `Object`, `[object Object]` is what you get when you simply convert that to a string. Are you trying to display the raw JSON string? The value of a particular property in the data?

Comment: @ewizard I try changing from "POST" to "GET" same problem is shows object Object

Comment: i dont think it would be as simple as just changing "POST" to "GET"

Comment: but im also not sure if this is ur problem - but if u are not putting anything into the database...u probably want a get request.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski I have some nvarcher(max) and I would like to display that in my div

Comment: what elements does `msg` contain? As GôTô answers, `html(msg.something)`

Comment: @User911 We need to know what `msg` contains. Add `console.log(msg);` in your `success` callback function and add the results of the log to your question. `msg` is an object. There is most likely a property in that object that contains the data you need. You need to know what that property is though.

Comment: look at this - post vs get http://www.w3schools.com/Jquery/jquery_ajax_get_post.asp

Comment: @User911 Can you share a snippet of the JSON from the response so we can see how it's defined? And, in what format or arrangement are you wanting them displayed? There isn't really a default you can use, so you have to specify.

Comment: Please check the server side script also. [Refer this link][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20854469/calling-to-json-file-in-asp-net-mvc-4

Comment: like - what data are you sending with your request that you have to send?

Comment: if you dont need to send anything with your request - use get

Comment: @ewizard I do agree that by W3C definitions this should be a `GET` request rather than a `POST`, but for all intents and purposes of adding the content to the `<div>` this is irrelevant. It's the return value that should be reviewed. The OP is receiving a value back but they don't understand how to place the value in the `<div>` using the object notation.

Comment: @War10ck yah - i think i get that - just wanted to point that out

Comment: @War10ck not trying to think about how he is messing up with jquery functions right now :)

Comment: I think OP is more confused now than when he asked the question :)

Comment: I had to place a foreach loop to get the data. I dont know why but it works.But thanks for helping guys.

Answer (score 3):

`.val` (value) has no meaning for a div.

To set the div inner text:

```
$('.someText').text(msg);
```

To set its html content:

```
$('.someText').html(msg);
```

Then it depends what you get and how you want to display your stuff. You might want to check `JSON.stringify` to make sure what your `msg` looks like (`$('.someText').text(JSON.stringify(msg));`)

Comment: for me html dont work but text do, however I am  getting [object Object] on my screen

Comment: are u sure you want a post request? not a get request?

Comment: @User911 I updated, what do you have in `msg`? What do you want to display exactly?