# How to make this javascript more dynamic using razor?

Tags: javascript, razor, model-view-controller, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2015

**Problem**

I am trying to adapt this [javascript](http://codepen.io/phantomesse/pen/WbJYam) (not my own) to be more dynamic for razor. However, it is becoming more clear to me that Razor was designed for being embedded in HTML and not javascript.

I want to be able to use razor to put variables into javascript so I can draw custom grids. One might be 5 x 3 and another might be 3 x 5.

Disclaimer: *learning javascript and I am working hard to improve*

**Code**

Here is a brief snippet of code discussing my problem. It is obviously not complete, but gives an idea of what has gone wrong:

I have placed my entire source code [here](https://github.com/HeathWillCode/SampleLibrary).

```
     @model SampleLibrary.Models.Shelf

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Details</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/grid.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {

        //This is dummy code for now. I need to figure out how to generate this based on label type in the future
        var columns = ['Column #1', 'Column #2', 'Column #3', 'Column #4'];
        var rows = ['Row #1', 'Row #2', 'Row #3'];




        // This is broken very badly - should be getting the following  values
        //model.columns = 4 and model.rows = 3
        var number_of_products = model.columns * model.rows;
```

**Error Message**

I no longer get the previous error message as I showed earlier. Instead, I will get the page...but no grid. I used firebug on mozilla and it is telling me that model is not defined. What the hey?

**Attempts**

My first attempts were really naive

- At first I thought it might be because javascript was being called before the model info was available, but tried this `$(document).ready(function ()`
- I thought perhaps I should just invoke the model as `Model.columns`
- I tried adding `<text></text>` syntax and it will not even build with that

**Summary**

The last part has clued me into my approach might be wrong. So I am thinking something like as follows:

- rewrite the function to take arguments `function(column, row, whateverElse)`

  - The arguments will be stuff like model.column, model.row, and model.whateverElse
- I could then move the javascript to it's own location. Name it something like grid.js.
- But here is where my brain totally explodes. How can I feed it the values I need to from razor in my view?

Right now I know how to move function into it's own file by putting it in something like grid.js using something like 
`<script src="~/lib/grid.js"></script>`

However, when I call that in a view, how in the heck can I feed it special values like `function(@model.column, @model.row, @model.whateverElse)`

Is this the right track? Or am I going towards outer space on this idea? Any assistance rendered would be deeply appreciated.

Comment: This isn't a problem with your JavaScript. The problem is in C#, how is the view generated?

Comment: Looks like your route is passing in a string as a model rather than Application.Models.Shelf

Comment: It appears that you aren't calling the View with a Application.Models.Shelf object.

Comment: @RobertMcKee I'll double check again, but I defined it in my view. As @ model Application.Models.Shelf, so in my view code I try to invoke it as model.columns and so on.

Comment: @AnotherDev The view takes in shelf and prints details about a particular shelf I have. I am trying to draw a grid of it. The eventual idea is to have a visual representation of what books are checked out and which ones are present. This is only proof of concept project, for learning purposes on my own time.

Comment: Firebug won't show the models object because the model is a server-side model, and doesn't exist on the client.

Comment: Yep, I had to pass the model in as a json object, but I am increasing convinced my approach is not ideal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest approach is to stop creating the table in javascript and let razor do it for you, and modify the javascript to handle interacting with the HTML that razor renders.  If all you care about it resizing the grid, then you can pass the columns and rows in via a model or viewbag if you prefer.

`var columns = ['Column #1', 'Column #2', 'Column #3', 'Column #4'];`

becomes:

```
var columns = [@{
foreach(var colname in Model.Columns)
{
<text>'@colname'</text>
}
}];
```

Another approach is to use data attributes, like this:
`<div id="products-wrapper" data-columns="@Model.columns" data-rows="@Model.rows">` which makes it very easy to move all your javascript out of the page entirely.  You would just include something like this in one of your javascript files (assuming you also have jQuery):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var cols=$('#products-wrapper').data('columns');
var rows=$('#products-wrapper').data('rows');
yourfunction(cols,rows);
});
```

You can also combine the data-attributes with ajax to have your javascript library call a webservice that returns json that you use to populate your grid as well. 
`<div id='products-wrapper' data-url='@Action.Url("getdata")'>` then write your javascript to pick up the url, call it, and then use the result to populate your grid.  This is definitely the most scaleable approach as you can use output caching to cache the page (assuming nothing else changes on it) and have the client cache it as well.

Comment: I am afraid that the approach you gave regarding data attributes with ajax is beyond what I have tried to date. Do you have documents or an example that demonstrates this idea to further my learning? Also, I will add my model and view to avoid confusion about what I am trying to do. Please be patient.

Comment: `data-` attributes are just a way to store information on tags to use on javascript. `$('selector').data('name')` think of it a shortcut for doing `$('selector').attr('data-name')`. This is the way to go btw. Great answer!

Comment: Your controller action for shelf/details looks correct now.  I would use the data attributes approach, which should be a fairly simple thing to implement.  Let me know if you have any other questions -- perhaps we could take it to a chat.

Comment: As for  how to AJAX calls, here a stack overflow answer to help you out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20854469/calling-to-json-file-in-asp-net-mvc-4

Comment: The above thread is pretty good.  You can learn a little something from each of the answers there.  The first one is a decent answer and touches into why to not hardcode urls in javascript (although he uses script on the page vs data-* attributes like I suggested). The second shows how to wrap the ajax call in document ready and how to parse the result.  The third shows an example on how to pass parameters into the ajax call, and uses .done instead of success (which I prefer).

Answer (score 1):

You can fix it by removing

```
@model Application.Models.Shelf
```

But the problem is best fixed by identifying what is being passed to the view and fixing it there.

It says you're passing a string, but it is expecting a Application.Models.Shelf object

Comment: I gave you an upvote for replying. Thank you. I know that is what the error says, but I am not sure I believe it. I might take a look at the controller to be sure I am indeed passing in a Shelf? I defined one in the view.

Comment: Yeah, I would double check to make sure that you're passing in a shelf. You could also check by placing a debug to see the value of model.

Comment: I did a major update on my post and put my entire source code up. There is a lot of work I have to do in order to make my grids dynamic, but I cannot even get the javascript to recognize my model in the view.